# Can anyone explain, Im learning Pointers in C, Here While running the code, why it asking 2 inputs when I wrote code to take single input

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void square(int *n);
int main(){
  int number;printf("Enter number : ");
  scanf("%d\n", &number);

  square(&number);
  return 0;
  }
void square(int *n){
*n=(*n)*(*n);
printf("Square : %d\n", *n);
}
```

This is my code, Here while running, it taking two inputs to run. I don't why. Can anyone explain this.

Comment: Please do not post images. Post [mre] code. Please refer to the help pages and maybe take the tour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try removing the `\n` from your scanf.

`scanf` will try to consume each of the specifiers you are giving it. You are telling it to expect a 'newline', so it will consume the first newline you supply by hitting 'enter'. Essentially you are telling your program to expect the user to hit Enter twice.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void square(int *n);
int main(){
  int number;printf("Enter number : ");
  scanf("%d", &number);

  square(&number);
  return 0;
}
void square(int *n){
    *n=(*n)*(*n);
    printf("Square : %d\n", *n);
}
```

Comment: Now its working perfectly, Can explain why it was happening, since \n is to print new line? and thank you.

Comment: Just amended my answer to add an explanation @koushik.

Comment: I didn't even know that. Thanks for telling me (and everyone else).